# Add a class to a button if aria-valuenow = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input

I'm trying to find a way to add a class `testing` to a button if the input has a `aria-valuenow` is 0.

My code so far:

```js
(function() {
  if($('.plyr__volume input').attr('aria-valuenow')=="0"){
    $('.js-volume').addClass('test');
  } else {
    $('.js-volume').removeClass('test');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="plyr__control js-volume" data-plyr="mute"></button>
  <div class="plyr__volume">
  <input data-plyr="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" 
  autocomplete="off" role="slider" aria-label="Volume" aria-valuemin="0"
  aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" id="plyr-volume-2587" style="--value:0%; 
  width: 0px; left: 200px;" aria-valuetext="0.0%" class="plyr__tab-focus">
</div>
```

Comment: `(function() {` should be `$(function() {`

Comment: What are you planning to use that class for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

> It is a design pattern which is also known as a Self-Executing Anonymous Function and contains two major parts. The first is the anonymous function with lexical scope enclosed within the `Grouping Operator ()`. This prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as polluting the global scope.
>
> The second part creates the immediately executing function expression () through which the JavaScript engine will directly interpret the function.

Your code is not executing at all, specify `()` at the end to make it an [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

**Demo:**

```js
(function() {
  var val = $('.plyr__volume input').attr('aria-valuenow');
  if(val == "0") $('.js-volume').addClass('test');
  else  $('.js-volume').removeClass('test');
})();
```

```css
.test{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="plyr__control js-volume" data-plyr="mute">My Button</button>
<div class="plyr__volume">
  <input data-plyr="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" autocomplete="off" role="slider" aria-label="Volume" aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="0.0%" class="plyr__tab-focus">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `()` on last when create function.  Self-executing anonymous function need that `()`.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  if ($('.plyr__volume input').attr('aria-valuenow') == "0") {
    $('.js-volume').addClass('test');
    console.log($('.js-volume').attr('class'));
  } else {
    $('.js-volume').removeClass('test');
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="plyr__control js-volume" data-plyr="mute"></button>
<div class="plyr__volume">
  <input data-plyr="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" autocomplete="off" role="slider" aria-label="Volume" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" id="plyr-volume-2587" style="--value:0%; 
width: 0px; left: 200px;" aria-valuetext="0.0%" class="plyr__tab-focus">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to execute this function, so you need to add `()` just before the final `;`:

```
(function() {
  if ($('.plyr__volume input').attr('aria-valuenow') == "0") {
    $('.js-volume').addClass('test');
  } else {
    $('.js-volume').removeClass('test');
  }
})();
```

This function now works, and adds `test` class when `aria-valuenow` is 0. However, since (at least in this example) the input always has `aria-valuenow` attribute set to 0 and the button doesn't have `test` class initially, the `else` block seems to be totally pointless if the function is meant to run only once when the page is loaded.