# How to add a class based on programmatically changed data in input aria-valuenow

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, plyr.js

I asked a question earlier about how to "[Add a class to a button if aria-valuenow = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132663/add-a-class-to-a-button-if-aria-valuenow-0)" and I got a solution but I assumed that it would change when the slider in the input goes to zero.

It only works what was loaded in `aria-valuenow`. For example, if `aria-valuenow=50` was loaded then the code won't work but if `area-valuenow=0` is loaded, then it works.

So how do you add a class to a div based on an input where the value is  programmatically changed?

Code:

```
<div class="plyr__control js-volume" data-plyr="mute">My Button</div>
<input data-plyr="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" 
autocomplete="off" role="slider" aria-label="Volume" aria-valuemin="0"
aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="*programmatically changes*" id="plyr-volume-2587" style="--value:0%; 
width: 0px; left: 200px;" aria-valuetext="0.0%" class="plyr__tab-focus">
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
var val = $('.plyr__volume input').attr('aria-valuenow');
if(val == "0") $('.js-volume').addClass('test');
})();
```

Working example with input changing values - 
https://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/JQeEry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need extra attribute (*aria-valuenow*), you can check the *value* on *input* event based on which you can add/remove the class:

**Demo:**

```js
(function() {
  $('#plyr-volume-2587').on('input',function(){
    if(this.value == '0')
      $('.js-volume').addClass('test')
    else
      $('.js-volume').removeClass('test')
  });
  $('#plyr-volume-2587').trigger('input');
})();
```

```css
.test{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plyr__control js-volume" data-plyr="mute">My Button</div>
<input data-plyr="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" 
autocomplete="off" role="slider" aria-label="Volume" aria-valuemin="0"
aria-valuemax="100" id="plyr-volume-2587" style="" aria-valuetext="0.0%" class="plyr__tab-focus">
```

Comment: I would advise to use [jQuery#toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of manually adding/removing class.

Comment: @Mamun This is great but it changes when I release the click. Anyway to get it to automatically change over. I tried `$('#plyr-volume-2587').on('change');`, didn't work

Comment: @GregorySchultz, you can try *input* event instead of *change*, updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: Works. Thanks again.